# why is ID undefined and how do I define it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Stars.js

```
export default class Stars extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            starLevel: 0
        }
        this.handleStars = this.handleStars.bind(this)
    }

    handleStars(props){
        if (`stars-${props.id}` > 0 && `stars-${props.id}` < 6){
            this.setState.starLevel = `stars-${props.id}.value`
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h3>{this.state.starLevel}</h3>
                <input id={`stars-${this.props.movie.id}`}></input>
                <button onClick={this.handleStars}>Submit Stars</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

movielist.js

```
return(
            <div className="container">
                {movies.map((movie) => (
                    <div>
                        <Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie} title={movie.title} image={movie.image} description={movie.description} id={movie.id} />
                        <Stars id={movie.id}/>
                    </div>
                ))}
                
            </div>
```

In the input script in render()/stars.js, the id keeps coming up as undefined. I tried props.id, this.props.movie.id, movie.id, id. nothing works. I'm trying to get it to read the value of the input and set the starlevel to it. My full code is available for those who need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small mistake in accessing the `id` prop.

You are passing the `id` prop, which means that you should access it using `this.props.id` not `this.props.movie.id`

So, instead of `` <input id={`stars-${this.props.movie.id}`}></input> ``.

You should do it like this: `` <input id={`stars-${this.props.id}`}></input> ``